# How to run SublimeREPL on remote python

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I want to run my python code on a remote environment (I have more cores/RAM etc...) and I have no idea how to do that in SublimeREPL. Do I just update the python_virtualenv_paths?

from:

```
"python_virtualenv_paths": [
    "~/.virtualenvs",  // virtualenvwrapper
    "~/.venv"  // venv.bash https://github.com/wuub/venv
],
```

to:

```
"python_virtualenv_paths": [
    "~/.virtualenvs",  // virtualenvwrapper
    "~/.venv",  // venv.bash https://github.com/wuub/venv
    "ssh my_remote"
],
```